# How to programmatically press a key exactly the same as if it were pressed on a keyboard?

Tags: delphi, vbscript

Does anyone know how to programmatically press a key exactly the same as if it were pressed on a keyboard?
PostMessage fails, SendInput fails, keybd_event fails, SendMessage fails and I even tried the unusual way of mimicing a key press using the Vcl.Touch.Keyboard. I even wrote a quick vb script file calling sendkeys which also failed.
I have been have having trouble trying doing this on a program called Sellerdeck http://www.sellerdeck.com/

I have tried all of the following, they all work with notepad but fail on this program.
The window is successfully brought to the forground by

```
procedure bringToForegroung;
Var
findhandle1 : cardinal;
begin
findhandle1 := FindWindow(NIL, 'Business Plus - Test site: Online Catalogue');
ShowWindow(findhandle1,SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(findhandle1);
end;
```

### 1.

```
procedure SendF10;
Var
findhandle1 : cardinal;
begin
findhandle1 := FindWindow(NIL, 'Business Plus - Test site: Online Catalogue');
ShowWindow(findhandle1,SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(findhandle1);
PostMessage(findhandle1, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F10, 0);
PostMessage(findhandle1, WM_KEYUP, VK_F10, 0);
end;
```

### 2.

```
 procedure SendAltF;
var
  KeyInputs: array of TInput;
  //--------------------------------------------
  procedure KeybdInput(VKey: Byte; Flags: DWORD);
  begin
    SetLength(KeyInputs, Length(KeyInputs)+1);
    KeyInputs[high(KeyInputs)].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    with  KeyInputs[high(KeyInputs)].ki do
    begin
      wVk := VKey;
      wScan := MapVirtualKey(wVk, 0);
      dwFlags := Flags;
    end;
  end;
begin
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, 0);                 // Alt
  KeybdInput(Ord('F'), 0);
  KeybdInput(Ord('F'), KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);
  KeybdInput(VK_MENU, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP);   // Alt
  SendInput(Length(KeyInputs), KeyInputs[0], SizeOf(KeyInputs[0]));
end;
```

### 3.

```
procedure SendKey2(Wnd,VK : Cardinal; Ctrl,Alt,Shift : Boolean);
var
  MC,MA,MS : Boolean;
begin
  // Try to bring target window to foreground
  ShowWindow(Wnd,SW_SHOW);
  SetForegroundWindow(Wnd);

  // Get current state of modifier keys
  MC:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL))>127;
  MA:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU))>127;
  MS:=Hi(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))>127;

  // Press modifier keys if necessary (unless already pressed by real user)
  if Ctrl<>MC then keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,Byte(MC)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Alt<>MA then keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,Byte(MA)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Shift<>MS then keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,Byte(MS)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

  // Press key
  keybd_event(VK,0,0,0);
  keybd_event(VK,0,KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);

  // Release modifier keys if necessary
  if Ctrl<>MC then keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0,Byte(Ctrl)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Alt<>MA then keybd_event(VK_MENU,0,Byte(Alt)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
  if Shift<>MS then keybd_event(VK_SHIFT,0,Byte(Shift)*KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
end;
```

### 4.

```
procedure SendF10v2;
Var
findhandle1 : cardinal;
begin
findhandle1 := FindWindow(NIL, 'Business Plus - Test site: Online Catalogue');
ShowWindow(findhandle1,SW_SHOW);
SetForegroundWindow(findhandle1);
SendMessage(findhandle1, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_F10, 0);
SendMessage(findhandle1, WM_KEYUP, VK_F10, 0);
end;
```

### 5.

```
uses
  Vcl.Touch.Keyboard, Vcl.Touch.KeyboardTypes;
type
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
protected        {i.e. dont make form active}
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override; {i.e. dont make keyboard form active}


procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
 begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do
  begin
    ExStyle   := ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
    WndParent := GetDesktopwindow;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  KeyData: TKeyData;
begin
KeyData := VKey(VK_F10, -1);
SendKey(KeyData, ksDown);
SendKey(KeyData, ksUp);
end;
```

### 6. (VBS)

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\SellerDeck 2013\Catalog.exe"" /s ""Test site"" /n Administrator /w Administrator", 0, True
Wscript.Sleep 10000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
objShell.SendKeys "%F"
WScript.Quit
```

As I said all, of these work in notepad, otherwise I would think it was my PC that was the problem.
I am trying to automate some basic tasks on this Sellerdeck program. Is there anyway to exactly mimic a key press? I hope it is just that I am missing something really basic.

Comment: Option 7. [`have you considered this ?`](http://i.imgur.com/Ppqzv7v.jpg). Now seriously, have you inspected what does that program use as an input window (e.g. with Spy++ tool) ? It can be *anything*, and at this time you are actually asking us to download and run that software, which is not good for this site.

Comment: Been there and done it, this has been giving me a headache. 
    SendMessage(b, WM_COMMAND, 50003, 0); 
For example should be the correct ID for "Find" on the edit menu but doesn't work. There is a hierarchy of 2 windows classes which I can get the handle of but nothing doing... Hence my question of exactly mimicking keyboard entry.

Comment: Have you ever thought that the program which is troubeling you might be using keyboard hook instead of processing Windows messages? If it is so it is posible that the program operates with keyboard scan codes isntead of VKey values.

Comment: Nice idea, I hadn't thought of it at all but checked it as below and still no response.

Comment: You should contact the developers of sellerdeck and ask them how to automate their program.

Comment: There are a lot of VB programs with this behaviour not all of these offer any automation assistance, it would be nice to find a workable keyboard hook...

Comment: @Reallyethical: It's not much help to you, but fwiw there is a similar problem trying to do a "SendKeys" with the current version of Adobe Acrobat Reader.  If you can google something that works with Reader, it would definitely be worth trying with sellerdeck.

Comment: @MartynA Actually it's not Sellerdeck I have been working on but another similar app. I have registered a keyboard which is working but there must be a better solution.

Comment: ... naive proposal: what about adding some ms "sleep" inbetween the DOWN/UP messages?

Comment: Nice try Arnaud, but no.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are sending the commands to the wrong Window handle. Perhaps the main application window, returned by FindWindow(), is not the one handle keystokes.

Try to use a debug tool, like WinSight (ws32.exe - which was shipped in older versions of Delphi), to guess the right handle...

Comment: +1. [GiPo WindowManager](http://www.gibinsoft.net/gipoutils/deskutil/) is a freeware utility that, among other things, can be used to find windows.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine for me:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  keybd_event(VK_MENU, $b8, 0, 0);
  keybd_event(VK_F4, $8f, 0, 0);
  keybd_event(VK_F4, $8f, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
  keybd_event(VK_MENU, $b8, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
end;
```

The required function is the following:

> void keybd_event(BYTE **bVirtualKey**, BYTE **bScanCode**, DWORD **dwFlags**,
>   DWORD **dwExtraInfo**);

This syntax must be used:

- **bVirtualKey**: Virtual Keycode of keys. E.g., VK_RETURN, VK_TAB…
- **bScanCode**: Scan Code value of keys. E.g., 0xb8 for “Left Alt” key.
- **dwFlags**: Flag that is set for key state. E.g., KEYEVENTF_KEYUP.
- **dwExtraInfo**: 32-bit extra information about keystroke.

The following link summarizes all information on the function together in detail:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7305/Keyboard-Events-Simulation-using-keybd-event-funct

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I've seen about 30 examples of keybd_event and yours was the only one to explain and use bScanCode... it gave me hope... it works in notepad... but does absolutely nothing in this sellerdeck program... despair... the physical key press Alt F4 brings up an exit dialogue of course..

Comment: Though not the correct answer this is a good explanation of keyboard event.